# Starting of VMs based on tags that we defined in azure

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I want to start the VM that have specific tag.
For example if my VM having the tag as **Dept:Finance** then by using azure cli command `az vm start` I should able to start the vms which are having the above tag.

I found one CLI command that will give the list of vms that was having the same tag like below
`az resource list --tag Dept=Finance`
By using the above command how I can start the above tag associated VMs

Please help me with the Azure CLI command to start the vms that are having the same tag.

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell:

```
$vms = az resource list --tag Dept=Finance --resource-type=Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines | convertfrom-json

foreach($vm in $vms)
{
  az vm start -g $vm.resourceGroup -n $vm.name
}
```

Comment: Can u please suggest me with any CLI command.?

Comment: @G.A what do you mean? those are CLI commands. If you are looking for a single command, that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results:

**In Azure CLI:**

Here i have taken `dept and finance` as tag when creating Vm and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli) :

```
$x=az graph query -q "Resources | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' | where tags contains 'finance'| project name, resourceGroup" |ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($emo in $x)
{

az vm start -g $emo.data.resourceGroup -n $emo.data.name
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**In Azure PowerShell:**

Alternatively you can do in PowerShell to get vms started as below:

Here i have taken `dept and finance` as tag when creating Vm and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-0.10.0) :
Use below script to start Vms with similar tag:

```
$x=Get-AzVM -Name * | where {($_.Tags.dept -eq "finance")}   
foreach($emo in $x)
{
  Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $emo.ResourceGroupName -Name $emo.Name
}
```

**Output:**

[image]